# PHP cURL - Strange problem with curl_setopt

Tags: php, curl

I have a very strange problem, here is my code :

```
function myFunction($id, $name, $secret) {

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.myurl.com/api');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
                 http_build_query(
                    array(
                        'Client_id'     => $id,
                        'Client_secret' => $secret, // $secret = Ve6UZ0cox=ry?2F9>qegmB:NCh?EQS?]cKmkjeHjS=3t1=E<RJ
                        'Client_name'   => $name
                    )));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $results = curl_exec($ch);
        $results = json_decode($results, true);

        print_r($results);

        curl_close ($ch);

        // curl_close($curl);
        return $results['Token_type'].' '.$results['Access_token'];
    }
```

The code above doesn't work, probably due to special chars in $secret.
But, when I directly write the $secret value, it works!

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
                     http_build_query(
                        array(
                            'Client_id'     => $id,

                            // Now, it works!
                            'Client_secret' => 'Ve6UZ0cox=ry?2F9>qegmB:NCh?EQS?]cKmkjeHjS=3t1=E<RJ'
                            'Client_name'   => $name
                        )));
```

Conclusion:

```
'Client_secret' => $secret // Doesn't work
'Client_secret' => 'Ve6UZ0cox=ry?2F9>qegmB:NCh?EQS?]cKmkjeHjS=3t1=E<RJ' // Work!
```

And yes, I tried this: `die($secret);`, which displays `Ve6UZ0cox=ry?2F9>qegmB:NCh?EQS?]cKmkjeHjS=3t1=E<RJ` as well.

What can you do please? Thank you for helping. ;-)

Cheers,
Seb

Comment: Could you share the code where you call the myFunction. Need to know how parameters are passed

Comment: I would remove http_build_query. Not really needed when passing an array unless you don't want the multipart/form-data content-type header added automatically.

Comment: Firstly why are you transmitting a secret that defeats the point of the secret, the reason is there will be some strange escaping on the string inside quotes you

Comment: Define "not works". What happens when it does not work?

Comment: Something is wrong with how you set the `$secret` var in the first place. Because if you do `die($secret);` and it spits out what you have shown... it contains extra double quotes on each end (die() doesn't add double quotes).

Comment: @Rinsad Ahmed sure, here is the call (simple) : myFunction($id, $name, $secret);

$id, $name and  $secret come from data base.

Comment: Could the output of `die` be shown as HTML (i.e. could one of the `>` be a `&gt;`)? To be sure, use "view source" in the browser.

Comment: Resolved! Thank you all for replies. I just added html_entity_decode($secret), like this:
'Client_secret' => html_entity_decode($secret)
And it works now. ;-)